# How do I query multiple ranges on multiple google sheet Tabs with multiple conditions?

Tags: google-sheets

Im want to populate a spreadsheet from two other tabs in the same workbook  I believe I need a filter / query / arrayformula to do this:

if  Cutulator!H2:H says "save" Then lookup the Value in  column A of that row , next look for a match in  Service!B2:B and select all columns in each row with that same  value , return all  with values greater  than 0 an not blank .
thanks in advance ive been struggling with this.
Im not asking for somebody to do everything for me I would just appreciate some formula examples or advice to help me to move forward.
Jarrod

[GSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VxXsSuIyV67aKeuxiyWWo3tXqf8cyL05ZMdh8V7_dc0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

To grab the values in Service column B you can use a filter function with a "+" after each criteria to pull where any column matches. You can use array brackets to combine multiple functions into one formula seperated by a semicolon. [See documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en). For example you could add two filters like such:

```
={FILTER(Cutulator!A2:A,PROPER(Cutulator!H2:H)="Save");
 FILTER(Service!B2:B,Service!Q2:Q>0+Service!R2:R>0+Service!S2:S>0)}
```

Comment: Thanks Torey, I'm having trouble getting your formula to show anything other than the Service!B2:B column.

Comment: Sorry still not having any luck did you look at the example in the attached sheet?

Comment: Try creating an example sheet of what you are looking to do to help the community understand your objective. Also make sure you understand the syntax, which will help you use these techniques for your specific needs; my answer is simply an example of how you could start to complete your task